# Android: Crash due to adding another cursor

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor

This is my ContactManager.java

```
package com.example.android.contactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public final class ContactManager extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{

    public static final String TAG = "ContactManager";

    private Button mAddAccountButton;
    private ListView mContactList;
    private boolean mShowInvisible;
    //public BooleanObservable ShowInvisible = new BooleanObservable(false);
    private CheckBox mShowInvisibleControl;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created. Responsible for initializing the UI.
     */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        Log.v(TAG, "Activity State: onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_manager);

        // Obtain handles to UI objects
        mAddAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addContactButton);
        mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        mShowInvisibleControl = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.showInvisible);

        // Initialise class properties
        mShowInvisible = false;
        mShowInvisibleControl.setChecked(mShowInvisible);

        // Register handler for UI elements
        mAddAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mAddAccountButton clicked");
                launchContactAdder();
            }
        });
        mShowInvisibleControl.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "mShowInvisibleControl changed: " + isChecked);
                mShowInvisible = isChecked;
                populateContactList();
            }
        });

        mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        mContactList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        // Populate the contact list
        populateContactList();
    }

    /**
     * Populate the contact list based on account currently selected in the account spinner.
     */
    private void populateContactList() {
        // Build adapter with contact entries
        Cursor cursor = getContacts();

        String[] fields = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,

        };


        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_entry, cursor,
                fields, new int[] {R.id.contactEntryText});
        mContactList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Obtains the contact list for the currently selected account.
     *
     * @return A cursor for for accessing the contact list.
     */
    private Cursor getContacts()
    {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        //Log.i("Uri ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI" + ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null);

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
               //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA1
                };

        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + (mShowInvisible ? "0" : "1") + "'";
        //String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + (mShowInvisible.get() ? "0" : "1") + "'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        return this.managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }



    /**
     * Launches the ContactAdder activity to add a new contact to the selected account.
     */
    protected void launchContactAdder()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactAdder.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("TAG", "You clicked item " + id + " at position " + position);



        Cursor cursor = getContacts();
        Cursor emailCur = getContactsEmail();
        emailCur.isNull(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);

        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
//        String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
        //String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

        //Log.i("Address", "Testing" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)));

        // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListContact.class);
//        SingleListContact.PutDetails(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, name, address, position, null, null);
        SingleListContact.PutDetails(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, name, null);

        Log.i("Show Contact Clicked: ",  name + "Email: " + null);

        startActivity(i);

    }

    private Cursor getContactsEmail()
    {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        //Log.i("Uri ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI" + ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null);

        String[] projection = new String[]
                {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
//                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.DATA1
                //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA
                };
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + (mShowInvisible ? "0" : "1") + "'";
        //String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + (mShowInvisible.get() ? "0" : "1") + "'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
//
        return this.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, selectionArgs, null);
    }


}
```

Before adding the emailCur, everything is working fine, but after add in the code in order to get the contactperson details, everything crashed! May i have solution here? Logcat as below:

```
 12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:262)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1550)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at com.example.android.contactmanager.ContactManager.getContactsEmail(ContactManager.java:193)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at com.example.android.contactmanager.ContactManager.onItemClick(ContactManager.java:153)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3749)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1986)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-27 22:20:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(9792):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Something tells me this isn't "your" ContactManager.

Comment: sorry, it's not me for whole, an example from android SDK

Answer (score 0):

Add null check for emailCur before accessing values from it.

Comment: Add emailCur.isNull(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)) OR check emailCur.getCount() and check size is > 0.

Comment: Before accessing values from emailCur.

Comment: it's still not working...is that as what you mentioned before?